# Drawing functions starting from a specific point

Tags: php, math, gd

I have a problem drawing different functions with PHP (GD, of course). 
I managed to draw different functions but whenever the parameters of the function change - the function floats wherever it wants.
Let us say that I have a first function y=x^2 and I have to draw it from -5 to 5. This means that the first point would be at (-5;25). And I can move that to whatever point I want if I know that. But if I choose y=2x^2 with an interval x=(-5;5). The first point is at (-5;50). So I need help in calculating how to move any function to, let's say, (0;0).
The functions are parabola/catenary alike.

Comment: do you have some example code?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is find the maximum boundaries of the graph you are making. To do this you have to check each inflection point as well as the range bounds. Store each coordinate pair in an array

Part 1 [Range Bounds]:
Collect the coordinates from the range bounds.

```
<?php
$ybound[] = f($minX);
$ybound[] = f($maxX);
```

Part 2 [Inflections]:
This part is more difficult. You can either have a series of equations to solve for inflections for each type of parabola, or you can just brute force it. To do this, just choose a small increment, (what ever your small increment is for drawing the line), I will use 0.1

```
<?php
for($x = $minX; $x <= $maxX; $x += 0.1) {
    $ybound[] = f($x);
}
```

Note, if you brute force, you can skip Part 1, otherwise, it would be faster if you could figure out the inflections for the scope of your project

Part 3 [Min Max]:
Now you get the min and max values from the array of possible y values.

```
<?php
$minY = min($ybound);
$maxY = max($ybound);
```

Part 4 [Shift]:
Now that you have this, it should be very simple to adjust. You take the top left corner and set that to 0,0 by adjusting each new coordinate to that value.

```
<?php
$shiftX = -$minX;
$shiftY = $maxY;
```

With this info, you can also determine your image size

```
<?php
$imageX = $maxX - $minX;
$imageY = $maxY - $minY;
```

Then as you generate your coordinates, you will shift each one, by adding the shift value to the coordinate.

```
<?php
for($x = -$minX; $x <= $maxX; $x += 0.1) {
    $ycoor = $shiftY - f($x);
    $xcoor = $x + $shiftX;
    //draw ...
}
```

Drawing the axis is also easy,

```
<?php
$xaxis = $shiftY;
$yaxis = $shiftX;
```

(I think I have all my signs correct. Forgive me if they are off)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to determine the bounding box of your function. Then, you calculate the width and the height, and you normalize so it fits into a rectangle whose top left coordinate is (0,0). Maybe you will also need to scale the figure to get it at a specific size.